# Run DB Update method after Observable result RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

## Hello

**The App:** I have a very basic app which have some **Machines** *(name, id, total_income)* and some **Incomes** *(id, money, note, machines_id)*. On the first screen I allow the users to add a machine from a FAB which then I display it in a RecyclerView. When the user clicks any machine I navigate them to the second screen, where the user can see the name of the machine, total income and a RecyclerView with its corresponding Income; There's a FAB which enables them to add the income for that machine and refreshes the RecyclerView.

**The problem:** I been failing to translate from the conventional world to RxJava.

I have managed to make it work using **Room** *.allowMainThreadQueries()* and conventional methods.

**MachineViewModel**

```
public long updateByID(long id, double total_income){
    return machinesDB.getMachineDAO().updateMachineByID(id, total_income);
}
```

**MachineDAO**

```
@Query("update machines set total_income = :total_income where id = :id")
int updateMachineByID(long id, double total_income);
```

**MachineInfo Activity**

```
disposable.add(incomeViewModel.getIncomeOfMachine(id)
             .defaultIfEmpty(0.0)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(total_amount -> {
                     if (total_amount != null) {
                        // This works correctly using .allowMainThreadQueries() and conventional methods
                        machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount);

                        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
                        String formatted = formatter.format(total_amount);
                        mMoney.setText(formatted);

                        Toast.makeText(this, "MachineInfo: " + String.valueOf(machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         showMenu = true;
                     } else {
                         mMoney.setText("$0.0");
                     }
             }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "MachineInfo: ERROR", throwable )));
```

---

I know **Room** needs to be instantiated in a background thread and thats why I am using RxJava. But when I try to translate the above methods into **RxJava World** like the below methods I'm failing to update but not crashing, **"Return Value of the method is never used"**.

**MachineViewModel**

```
public Completable updateByID(long id, double total_income){
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> machinesDB.getMachineDAO().updateMachineByID(id, total_income));
}
```

**MachineDAO**

```
@Query("update machines set total_income = :total_income where id = :id")
int updateMachineByID(long id, double total_income);
```

**Try # 1: Failure**

```
private PublishSubject<Double> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
private Observable<Double> clickEvent = publishSubject;

/*
/ other stuff in here
*/

disposable.add(incomeViewModel.getIncomeOfMachine(id)
            .defaultIfEmpty(0.0)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(total_amount -> {
                        if (total_amount != null) {

                            publishSubject.onNext(total_amount);

                            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
                            String formatted = formatter.format(total_amount);
                            mMoney.setText(formatted);
                            showMenu = true;
                        } else {
                            mMoney.setText("$0.0");
                        }
                    }, throwable -> Log.d(TAG, "MachineInfo: ERROR")));

    disposable.add(clickEvent.subscribe(
            total_amount -> machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount)));
```

---

**Try # 2: Failure**

**MachineViewModel**

```
public Completable updateByID(long id, double total_income){
    return Completable.fromCallable(() -> machinesDB.getMachineDAO().updateMachineByID(id, total_income));
}
```

**MachineDAO**

```
@Query("update machines set total_income = :total_income where id = :id")
int updateMachineByID(long id, double total_income);
```

**MachineInfo Activity**

```
disposable.add(incomeViewModel.getIncomeOfMachine(id)
             .defaultIfEmpty(0.0)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(total_amount -> {
                     if (total_amount != null) {
                        // Completable.fromCallable()
                        machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount);

                        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
                        String formatted = formatter.format(total_amount);
                        mMoney.setText(formatted);

                        Toast.makeText(this, "MachineInfo: " + String.valueOf(machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         showMenu = true;
                     } else {
                         mMoney.setText("$0.0");
                     }
             }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "MachineInfo: ERROR", throwable )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by failing? Is the database not getting updated or are you getting some exceptions?

Anyway, the main problem I see is that you are not subscribing to your Completable objects - without this, they won't be executed.

So change:

```
machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount);
```

to for example:

```
machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();
```

and it will work (of course, you might wanna add specific Subscriber to `subscribe` method).

Comment: Added explanation on where Im failing. **"I'm failing to update but not crashing, "Return Value of the method is never used".** As per your answer: I added your example inside the First Observable and got this strange message = "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."

Comment: Sorry, it was late in the night :D it is of course supposed to be `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io())`, not `observeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io())`. I updated my answer :)

Comment: BTW the message wasn't strange. If we don't describe the thread at which it's supposed to subscribe, by default it will be executed on UI thread in Android, so indeed the access to database was done on UI thread, which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so **thanks to Michael** I managed to find the hole in the problem.

So apparently you can **Add Disposables** inside *Disposables*.

- You need to initialize the **Observable** and add its *.observeOn(etc).subscribeOn(etc).subscribe(etc)*"
- Add the disposable inside the disposable like this:

  ```
  disposable.add(incomeViewModel.getIncomeOfMachine(id)
          .defaultIfEmpty(0.0)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(total_amount -> {
                      if (total_amount != null) {

                          disposable.add(machineViewModel.updateByID(id, total_amount)
                                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                  .subscribe(
                                          () -> Log.d(TAG, "MachineInfo: COMPLETED"),
                                          throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "MachineInfo: ERROR", throwable )));

                          DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
                          String formatted = formatter.format(total_amount);
                          mMoney.setText(formatted);
                          showMenu = true;
                      } else {
                          mMoney.setText("$0.0");
                      }
                  }, throwable -> Log.d(TAG, "MachineInfo 2: ERROR")));
  ```

Im note sure if is a clean answer but it works.